# Internet Explorer xpath not finding element

Tags: internet-explorer, xpath

I am trying to find an element located at

```
xpath = //html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]
```

In Firefox this works, however in Internet Explorer it doesn't.  IE 
can find the element but it is at

```
//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]
```

I guess this could make sense given they probably format some source 
differently, my issue is that if I look at the source on the IE page, 
then to me the first one that works in FF looks correct.  If I put 
the source outputted from IE into FF then Firefox finds the element 
correctly at the location I am expecting.

I have the page source which I got from IE which can be found at 
http://pastebin.com/Vg9J7cxn.  Also included is the source from Firefox

Does anyone know why IE is unable to find the element?  I am finding the xpath 
by iterating back through the dom structure, so does anyone know a 
workaround I can use to find elements at these "IE" xpaths in the 
future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you get when you strip the content of the source down to just the structural elements:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div class='appOuterWrapper'>
            <div class='appHeaderContainer'>
                <div class='appHeader'>
                    <div class='appTop'>
                        <div class="appLogonOff"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="appCmsMenu">
                        <ul id="nav" class="top"></ul>
                        <div class="breadcrumbs">
                            <div class="crumbs"></div>
                            <div class="thedate"/>
                            <span/>
                        </div>
                        <script></script>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="containerWrapper cmsContent">
            <div class="appWholePage appContent">
                <div class="home-sidebar"></div>
                <div class="page-body home-page-content"></div>
                <div class="containment"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- <==== THIS IS INVALID -->
        <div class='appFooterContainer'>
            <div class='appFooter'>
                <span class='links'></span>
                <span class='copyright'></span>
            </div>
            <div class="TestAppitLink"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the same in both versions of the linked source. Notice my comment, which is pointing out an extra ending `div` tag:

```
</div><!-- <==== THIS IS INVALID -->
```

If you look at how my parser formatted the document (based on the structure above), you'll see that there is no element at:

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]
```

...because

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]
```

...only contains one `div`. (In other words, it agrees with IE.)

My guess is that **Firefox and IE are treating this input tree differently**, in an effort to present it to the XPath engine as a well-formed document.

**Options**:

- Fix the source document
- Approach the expression using classes, instead of position. You may find one that matches the tree in both browsers. For example:

  ```
  /html/body/div[@class='appOuterWrapper']/<rest_of_expression>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the first div (//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]), there is only one div child. I don't see how you could address a 2nd div.

What's the class of the div you're trying to get to?